# Favicon not showing for the page opened with window.open

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a page say A where I have added a link

```
<a href="#" ng-click="printMe()">print</a>
```

Now when I click on print the function does `window.open().document.write(html);`
This html variable contains html tags to show data in print view-

```
html="<html>";
html +="<head><link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/vnd.microsoft.icon' >";
....
...
```

This new page which opens in new tab fails to show favicon. whereas the same tag is used in parent page shows it. when i checked source it shows the ico image exists.

Comment: try type="image/x-icon" ...

Comment: You can not use relative URLs in that context – since your popup does not have any “base URL” that could be used to resolve them. Use an absolute URL instead.

Comment: No success with type="image/x-icon".

Comment: @CBroe Tried with absolute url like http://... It still does not show favicon. I even restarted grunt after changing the url. thx for help.

Comment: Do you see the browser make a request for the favicon in developer tools?

Comment: I don't see it in Developer tools but I can see it here 
chrome://net-internals/#events

Comment: Im having the same problem, essentially